# How frequently a Moderator should come and edit posts in a week or month in Pro Webmaster Stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

I noticed one Moderator hasn't seen the site (`webmasters.stackexchange.com`) after Dec 7, 2013 that’s why I’m asking this question. How frequently a Moderator should come and edit posts in Pro webmaster stack exchange per week or month? Is there any rules for moderator to come within certain period of days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no hard rules that govern how often a moderator *must* visit the site.

Certainly if a moderator hasn't been active in months, they get removed.  That was the case for the last election.   One of the current moderators hadn't been active since May and an election was held to replace them.

The moderation duties of this site can be handled pretty easily by three active moderators.  There is an extra so that one can take a vacation or have a busy period that doesn't allow them to spend as much time on Pro Webmasters without effecting the quality of the site.

The moderator that hasn't been seen for a while indicated in chat that December would be a very busy month with a lot of clients at his consulting business and that he should be able to spend more time on Pro Webmasters after Christmas.

---

It also appears that the "last seen" data may be buggy right now.   It looks like a bunch of data from the last few days got "lost".   As a moderator we have access to a dashboard that shows the activity counts for the moderators.   It shows the number of edits, responses, flags handled, votes, etc.  Those counts are all very low right now like it only has a couple days of data in it.  "Last seen" also appears to be inaccurate.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that its the month for loving, forgiving and giving ;) Sadly over the past 6 weeks I've been working my arse off to get to this point where I can have 2 weeks of comfort without endless calls and messing people around in the real world :P